# How can I use get a single value from my subquery in sparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using SparkSQL

```
spark.sql("""
        SELECT artist, count(distinct(song))
        FROM user_log_table WHERE artist =
       (SELECT artist
        FROM user_log_table
        GROUP BY artist
        ORDER BY count(artist) DESC
        LIMIT 1 )        
""").show()
```

This is my query, I ran the subquery only and it gave me a single value which is what I am looking for, then I want to use that value in the where clause but I get the error

> An error occurred while calling o22.sql.
> : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'user_log_table.`artist`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(count(DISTINCT user_log_table.`song`) AS `count(DISTINCT song)`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap 'user_log_table.`artist`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;

Answer (score 1):

You want the song count of the one artist with the maximum log entries. In case there are two artists with that same number of log entries, you pick one arbitrarily. At least this is what your query does. And you don't need a subquery for this:

```
SELECT
  artist,
  COUNT(DISTINCT song)
FROM user_log_table
GROUP BY artist
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This gives you one row with two values (artist and number of songs). You can remove `artist` or `COUNT(distinct song)` from the select clause, if you just want one of the two values of course.